# mysql 4.x login problem

Tags: mysql, authentication

I install php 5 and mysql 4.x and mysql 5.x on my windows server.
When I try to connect my sql 4 from php myadmin I got access denied for user@localhost USING password : yes

I try command line , and inform if I use mysql -uuser -p , I can login wihtout problem but if I use mysql -uuser@localhost -p , I got access denied error.

What is diffrence between user and user@localhost ? what setting is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will search for the user named after the -u parameter; **user@localhost** is not the value stored in the mysql.user table, so use **user**.  Note that if you want to specify the host, use the -h param:

```
mysql -u user -h localhost -p
```